# How to make Automapper use exact value without creating a new object

Tags: c#, automapper

How to make Automapper use exact value without creating a new object?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Program
{
    public class A { }

    public class B
    {
        public A Aprop { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public A Aprop { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cnf =>
            {
                // I really need this mapping. Some additional Ignores are present here.
                cnf.CreateMap<A, A>(); 
                // The next mapping should be configured somehow 
                cnf.CreateMap<B, C>(); //.ForMember(d => d.Aprop, opt => opt.MapFrom(...)) ???
            });
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B() {Aprop = a};
            C c = Mapper.Map<C>(b);
            var refToSameObject = b.Aprop.Equals(c.Aprop); // Evaluates to false
        }
    }
}
```

How should I change `cnf.CreateMap<B, C>();` line in order to make `refToSameObject` variable have `true` value? If I remove `cnf.CreateMap<A, A>();` it will work this way however I cannot remove it because sometimes I use automapper to update `A` classes from other `A` classes.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is to use `ConstructUsing` and set `Aprop` during the construction of `C`:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cnf =>
{
    cnf.CreateMap<A, A>(); 
    cnf.CreateMap<B, C>()
        .ConstructUsing(src => new C() { Aprop = src.Aprop })
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Aprop, opt => opt.Ignore());
});
```

This should work and isn't too painful assuming it's really just one property.